# Windows 8.1 Install Hangs and then blue screens

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Windows 8.1 machine with decent specifications which at random points hangs, freezes (so you can only move your mouse) and then blue screens.

I have contacted Microsoft Support but they have had to escalate to Tier 3 which they said don't respond for up to 2 weeks so I wonder if anyone can help with my issue.

I personally believe this to be a failing hard drive but would like to know otherwise, I have re-installed graphics drivers etc. but when using Spotify to listen to music when it crashes the song continues for a few seconds and then stops.

As already mentioned I have re-installed the graphics drivers and all are up to date, I know the more recent blue screen is NVIDIA but I am not sure if that is a red herring or not...

**Machine Details**

Windows is installed onto Disk 2 which is a 256GB Brand new SSD

Disk 3 is a 2TB internal hard drive used for applications and data etc...

Two NVIDIA 660-TI Graphics Cards installed in SLI

I also noticed these in my event viewer under system:

`An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk3\DR3 during a paging operation.`

Because of this I took it upon myself to run a check disk

[**Check Disk Results**](http://pastebay.net/1335186)

For some reason the log does not include everything but I would really like to have a suggestion as to whether it is worth going out and paying for a new hard drive or something else?

Thanks in advance!

*Please note: I only have three blue screens because when I am coding, working or whatever I tend to just restart the computer to get it to work again quickly so I can finish with what I am doing.*

**UPDATE**

I have since had 2 more blue screens for different reasons so I am now stuck...

**[Downloadable minidumps](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/blfhprs7g52hkfx/EAUswkvoBg)**

Comment: IME, freezing while still having mouse _is_ usually the hard drive (or less likely the drive controller).  Test the hard drive using the manufacturer's diagnostics. If it finds nothing, test memory for a day or two with Memtest86+. You also may want to strip down a bit, take out one the video cards, etc. and see if it acts any better.

Comment: I need the real dmp files. Upload them.

Comment: Strange, i have had two more with one being KERNAL and another NetBIOS interface? @magicandre1981 see update

Comment: You always get this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj154556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. But I can't really see anything useful from the dmp. update the BIOS to Version 4404 and see if this helps.

Comment: @magicandre1981 the BIOS is at the latest version, still an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue to have been the install of Windows and the disk I was using, have since changed the disk and re-installed on a new SSD, this fixed all of my issues